# Getting Error: "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType Field' does not declare a navigation property"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Created method:

```
 public List<Field> GetScheduleDetails()
 {    
     var schedulefields = DBcontextFactory.Context.Set<Field>).Include("ScheduleField").ToList();
 }
```

With the above method i am trying to fetch all joined(field.fieldid=schedulefield.fieldid) records from both tables. The field table is related with schedulefield table. Sorry if i am not familiar with technical terms.

Field Model:

```
public partial class Field : DOIEntity
{

    public Field()
    {
        this.FilerResponses = new HashSet<FilerResponse>();
        this.ScheduleFields = new HashSet<ScheduleField>();
    }

    public int FieldId { get; set; }
    public string FieldDisplayName { get; set; }
    public int FieldTypeId { get; set; }
    public string HelpText { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> OtherTextAllowed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ChoiceGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual FieldType FieldType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FilerResponse> FilerResponses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ScheduleField> ScheduleFields { get; set; }
}
```

ScheduleField Model:

```
public partial class ScheduleField
{

    [Key]
    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
    public int FieldId { get; set; }
    public byte SortOrder { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsMandatory { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentFieldId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentChoiceId { get; set; }

    public virtual Field Field { get; set; }
    public virtual Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
}
```

When I call the method I am getting this error:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'WorldBank.DOI.Data.Field' does not declare a navigation property with
>   the name 'ScheduleField'.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Your `Field` class does not have a `ScheduleField` property but instead a collection of it declared as `ScheduleFields`.

Comment: If i add public virtual ScheduleField ScheduleField {get;set;} will the problem resolve ?

Comment: It depends, is that what you really need? Do you need a single instance of `ScheduleField` in `Field`? If yes then what would you do with the collection of `ScheduleField`? Or maybe this is what you need:  `DBcontextFactory.Context.Set<Field>().Include("ScheduleFields")`

Comment: I actually trying to fetch all records from both tables(Field,Schedulefield).

Comment: It would be good if you can edit your question and provide as much information as needed so everybody here can help you. The more info you put in the easier it is for us to understand what "exactly" you are trying to do. For example, do you really need to fetch it that way? Since you need to fetch from both tables, can't you fetch 
"by each table"? Or do you need a relation between fetched records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the property name of the Field class in the Include string:

```
public List<Field> GetScheduleDetails()
{    
     var schedulefields = DBcontextFactory.Context.Set<Field>).Include("ScheduleFields").ToList();
}
```

This will eager load the ScheduleField objects associated with the Field objects.

Note, you can also eager load many levels. For example, if you want to eager load the schedules of the ScheduleField object as well you would do this:

```
public List<Field> GetScheduleDetails()
{    
   var schedulefields = DBcontextFactory.Context.Set<Field>).Include("ScheduleFields.Schedule").ToList();
}
```